# Is a context switch less expensive between processes with the same executable

Tags: caching, kernel, context-switch

## Question

Are there any notable differences between context switching between processes running the same executable (for example, two separate instances of `cat`) vs processes running different executables?

## Background

I already know that having the same executable means that it can be cached in the same place in memory and in any of the CPU caches that might be available, so I know that when you switch from one process to another, if they're both executing the same executable, your odds of having a cache miss are smaller (possibly zero, if the executable is small enough or they're executing in roughly the same "spot", and the kernel doesn't do anything in the meantime that could cause the relevant memory to be evicted from the cache). This of course applies "all the way down", to memory still being in RAM vs. having been paged out to swap/disk.

I'm curious if there are other considerations that I'm missing? Anything to do with virtual memory mappings, perhaps, or if there are any kernels out there which are able to somehow get more optimal performance out of context switches between two processes running the same executable binary?

## Motivation

I've been thinking about the Unix philosophy of small programs that do one thing well, and how taken to its logical conclusion, it leads to lots of small executables being forked and executed many times. (For example, 30-something `runsv` processes getting started up nearly simultaneously on Void Linux boot - note that `runsv` is only a good example during startup, because they mostly spend their time blocked waiting for events once they start their child service, so besides early boot, there isn't much context-switching between them happening. But we could easily image numerous `cat` or `/bin/sh` instances running at once or whatever.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context switching overhead is the same. That is usually done with a single (time consuming) instruction.

There are some more advanced operating systems (i.e. not eunuchs) that support installed shared programs. They have reduced overhead when more than one process accesses them. E.g., only one copy of read only data loaded into physical memory.

Comment: Since no more answers have accumulated in four years now, I'm going to trust that this is correct and comprehensive enough to be accepted as _the_ answer.